# How do I access a data value in d3 dynamically? (without using d.whatever)

Tags: javascript, select, d3.js

I am writing a d3 program where I am trying to change the opacity of my data points depending on a selected data parameter and value. Simplified, my code looks something like this:

```
var columnSelected = "name";
var attribute = "John";

svg.selectAll("circle").style("opacity",function(d){
  if(d.name == attribute) 
  {
   return 0;
  }
})
```

This works, but only if the column I want from the data is "name." I know there must be an easy way to access data based on dynamic values, but I can't seem to find it. Any ideas?

Comment: "*if the column I want from the data is "name."*": JavaScript is case-sensitive; looking at your example, you probably mean "Name" instead. As to your problem, you should be able to use `if(d[columnSelected] == attribute)` to dynamically access your data.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I knew it was something simple. Now I just need to fix the rest of it :)

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically access your data you could use standard JavaScript [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) which will, of course, work within functions called by d3.js as well as elsewhere:

```
var columnSelected = "name";
var attribute = "John";

svg.selectAll("circle").style("opacity",function(d){
  if(d[columnSelected] == attribute) 
  {
   return 0;
  }
});
```